# Дорожнотранспортные или дорожно-транспортные?

Tags: орфография

Столкнулась с написанием этого, казалось бы, простого слова. Написала слитно, но ворд подчеркивает.
А как на самом деле пишется это слово? Ворд предлагает в два слова, но мне что-то не верится. По-моему, либо слитно, либо через дефис.

Answer (score 3):

Дорожно-транспортный, дорожно-патрульный, дорожно-строительный - принято дефисное написание этих сложных прилагательных.

Дорожно-транспортное происшествие - это дорожное транспортное происшествие, здесь неоднородное сочинение исходных прилагательных. А вот в слове газетно-журнальный (газетный и журнальный) - однородное сочинение основ, можно поставить союз И.